# What does the & sign mean?

Tags: plc

In some Omron plc logic I have a move statement that looks like this

```
----------
|@Mov(021)
|        |
|        |
|&110    |
|        |
|        |
|D5000   |  
|        |
|(value) |
|        |
----------
```

Confused as to what the @ sign means and the & sign?

The reason i ask is, the value is always 0 , 110 , 120 (numbers)   but the only moves i find is 0 and &110  , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` sign (**in this case!!!** *) indicates a differential instruction. This means the instruction is only executed when the input makes an OFF to ON transition.

Example:

```
  12.34

---| | -------------------| MOV  |
                          | &110 |
                          | D5000|
```

For the above, any time `12.34` is ON the decimal value (indicated by `&`) 110 will be moved to `D5000`.  It will be stored as `[x006E]`.  If you instead used `#110` it would be moved as a HEX or BCD value (ie : `D5000` would contain `[x0110]` - a BCD value of 110 or a decimal value of 272, depending on how it is interpreted)

Consider now

```
  12.34

---| | -------------------| @MOV |
                          | &110 |
                          | D5000|
```

This will only move the value `&110` to `D5000` on a single PLC scan when `12.34` turns from OFF to ON.  If another instruction later writes to `D5000` while `12.32` remain ON then the above instruction will not overwrite it except if `12.34` turns OFF again, then back ON.  The `@`, then, makes the instruction a one-shot instruction - it doesn't work continuously but only once each time the input conditions are fully satisfied.

While different in meaning and implementation, the above rung would work the same as, for example :

```
  12.34

---|↑| -------------------|  MOV |
                          | &110 |
                          | D5000|
```

In the above, the `12.34` contact is differential and only turns on for one scan when `12.34` makes an OFF->ON transition.  Often, however, you may have more complex input logic such that a differential `@MOV` instruction, in place of differential contacts, is more convenient or sensible or even required for the desired behaviour.

If you are finding mystery values in your memory locations you can track down where they come from using the Address Reference Tool in CX-Programmer (**View -> Windows -> Address Reference Tool**  -- or *ALT+4*).  Clicking on the D-Memory location in Ladder will list all rungs where that address is used.  This should help you find where it is being written to in your program :

[image: Address Reference Tool]

*** Be careful with other uses of @ in Omron PLCs** -  [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9327806/327083)

Comment: Also i tried using the find address  for D5000  and it only shows 4 spots  and they are only moving values #0 and &110    guess ill have to do more diggin..

Comment: @GlenMorse Other instructions, like `BSET` or table instructions can move entire blocks - it could be something like that.  `DIST` can be a move to an address plus offset.  Pointer moves (see the 'be careful' link at the end above) can also move things indirectly (ie: `MOV @D300` could be a move to `D5000` if `D300` contained 5000).  Could be tricky to track down...

Answer (score 0):

The & signs means that the value is a decimal.

Comment: ok , so that explain the values 0 and 110.  But nowhere did i find &120..  Thus it must be something with the @Move(021) ?  Any idea what the @ sign means?

Comment: As far as I know (I'm not an Omron expert) the @Mov(021) is how the notation for the instruction is.
Your instruction says: move the decimal value 110 into memory location D5000
If my memory is correct. If you are seeing 0 and 120 in D5000 there must be other instructions working on that addres.